# Cardinality of codomain less than cardinality of domain implies the ring homomorphism is surjective

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\phi:X \rightarrow Y$ be a ring homomorphism where $|X|\geq|Y|$.

Is it true that $\phi$ must be surjective?  I feel like it is, but I don't know how to prove it.

Maybe I should add that assume $X$ and $Y$ are both unital.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def \Z{\mathbb Z}$
$f:\Z\to \Z/2\Z\times \Z/2\Z$
$\hspace{.75cm}n\mapsto(n+2\Z,n+2\Z)$

Really, just take any morphism $X\to Z$, for some other ring $Z$, then compose it with some homomorphism $Z\to Y$ which is not surjective. Here I used $\pi:\Z\to \Z/2\Z$ is the natural projection and $\Delta:\Z/2\Z\to \Z/2\Z\times \Z/2\Z$ is diagonal inclusion.

Comment: Is "homorohpsim" some fancy new technical term, or just a typo?

Answer (score 1):

Consider e.g. the inclusion homomorphism of $\mathbb R$ into $\mathbb C$.